# Is it possible to insert knobs on nodes in Nuke?

Tags: python, nuke

The main interface for adding knobs to nodes in nuke appears to be the `node.addKnob()` function.  The knobs are added in the order that the `addKnob` method is called.  Is there a way to insert knobs before other knobs that have already been created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Foundry support, it is *not* possible to insert knobs into existing nodes or groups.  The only option is to delete and recreate the set of knobs.